# Inter Annotator Agreement for Question Answering

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language, agreement-statistics, cohens-kappa

I would like to run an [Inter Annotator Agreement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-rater_reliability) (IAA) test for Question Answering. I've tried to look for a method to do it, but I wasn't able to get exactly what I need. I've read that there are [Cohen's Kappa coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen%27s_kappa) (for IAA between 2 annotators) and [Fleiss' Kappa coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fleiss%27_kappa) (for IAA between several).

However, it looks to me that these two coefficients can be used only for categorical answers. What I'm trying to do is a bit different. I want to evaluate IAA over extractive Question Answering, which means that the answer is a span of text.

For Example:

**Text**:

"Alzheimer's disease (AD) is a neurodegenerative disease that usually starts slowly and progressively worsens. It is the cause of 60–70% of cases of dementia. The most common early symptom is difficulty in remembering recent events. As the disease advances, symptoms can include problems with language, disorientation (including easily getting lost), mood swings, loss of motivation, self-neglect, and behavioral issues. As a person's condition declines, they often withdraw from family and society. Gradually, bodily functions are lost, ultimately leading to death. Although the speed of progression can vary, the typical life expectancy following diagnosis is three to nine years." (First part of [Wikipedia Alzheimer's Disease page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alzheimer%27s_disease))

**Questions**:

1. Which is the most common early symptom for AD?
2. Which are the symptoms of AD?

Now let's say that there are the answers from two different annotators (but they could be many):

**Answers from annotator 1**:

1. "difficulty in remembering recent events"
2. "problems with language, disorientation (including easily getting lost), mood swings"

**Answers from annotator 2**:

1. "difficulty in remembering recent events"
2. "problems with language, disorientation (including easily getting lost), mood swings, *loss of motivation, self-neglect, and behavioral issues*"

It looks clear that answers to question 2 for the annotators is different, so they do not agree in giving answers.

How can I calculate IAA between this set of answers? Or maybe IAA is not a good estimator in such case: which measure could I use then?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your objective. If the shorter answer is right, is the longer answer nearly as good, for your purposes, or just plain wrong?

If the latter, so all answers are simply right or wrong, then IAA is OK as a measure.

If the former, so answer quality is on a scale from 0 to 1, then the situation is more difficult. If there was some objective way to assign quality scores, then you could find the inter-annotator correlation. But there probably isn't.

I suggest that you investigate the real size of the challenge by getting the two annotators to discuss these cases, or a third annotator to review them. Maybe in such cases the shorter answer is usually the one you want, or maybe the longer answer is usually the one you want. Then you can deal with the situation fairly easily.

The problem is more difficult if the best answer is close to 50/50 between the short answer and the long answer, and you care about the difference. In that case, you will have to work to develop better guidelines for the annotators, and have another pass of annotation for all these cases.

Comment: Many thanks @chrishmorris. Anyway, apparently my doubt was simpler then I thought: as reported by [Rajpurkar](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.05250.pdf), IAA in Question Answering is the F1 score. "These results are still well behind human
performance, which is 86.8% F1 based on inter-
annotator agreement". So I think I will go with that, I "just" will have to pick which annotator is the reference.